# Handlebars refusing to change h1 inner text on nodejs render

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

My backend goes like this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(objectResponse.humidity);
    res.render('home',{umidade: objectResponse.humidity});
    console.log('home');
});



app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
  console.log("Aqui")
  console.log(req.body);

  axios.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+req.body.cidade+
  "&units=metric&appid=" + process.env.API
  + "&lang=pt").then(response => { 
    objectResponse.humidity =  response.data.main.humidity;
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    }).finally(response=>{
      console.log('finally')
      res.redirect('/')
    });
});
```

And then when the axios request return the results, i would redirect it to the main route, which updates the value for humidity using a wheater API, but even though this value reaches my front end, in the first request, when I update it, and call the API again, the inner html value refuses to change, I tried everything possible on DOM.

```
<h1 class="umidade mb-4">{{{umidade}}}</h1> // This H1 refuses to change
console.log({{{umidade}}}) // This changes when redirecting
```

Comment: When you save `objectResponse.humidity =  response.data.main.humidity;`, is objectResponse in any session? After ends app.post('/submit') handler, you didn't persist  objectResponse  to use in next call when you get "/" path.

Comment: I tried to use sessions also, but I think the problem is with the html, since the data is reaching the front-end at real time, but when it renders again the program doesn't update.

Comment: Put this code in your root server file (normally app.js): `global.objectResponse = {humidity: null};`. Then, change in your controllers from `objectResponse.humidity` to `global.objectResponse.humidity`. If not works, sorry!

Comment: I'm sorry for not aswering before, I was stuck at this code for a long time, hahaha. I changed it to an websocket using socket.io and now it works properly, the whole communication between server and client side is more straightforward, and by doing that I solved a future problem.